# Camel convert Java DSL to Spring DSL

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I'm new to Camel and I'm still learning about it and from my understanding you can do the same things in Spring DSL as Java DSL. What I'm wondering is how do you convert one to the other? Often I see examples of things in Java but want to

Comment: Give us the Java DSL to convert to Spring DSL, we'll help you.

Comment: Exception cause = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, 
Exception.class);

I want to be able to get the error message from the exchange.

Comment: exception processing is described [here](http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html)

Comment: But where do you want to put it?
That line is not Java DSL, just plain java inside a processor similar. `<simple>${property.CamelExceptionCaught}</simple>` pretty much extracts this property, but you need to so something, like saving it inside the body, some headers or similar.

You can still Spring DSL submit a java class and ivoke it to do such things in java, if you want to do something extra.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the difference between `Java DSL` and `Spring XML` is that first is written completely in `Java` language through `RouteBuilder#configure()` method and second is written in `XML`. You can use ANY to achieve things you need. In some cases `Java DSL` is more `clean`, while in other cases `XML` configuration file could be preferable.

[Here](http://camel.apache.org/java-dsl.html) is the example of Java DSL, while [here](http://camel.apache.org/spring.html) is Spring XML.

Comment: I understand the differences between them but if I see an example of how to do something in Java DSL and I'm using Spring XML, how do I translate it to Spring XML? There seems to be a lot more examples in Java.

Comment: you can translate `Java DSL` to `Spring XML` only manually. To do that you should know both very well.